# Gigaware wireless-n usb 2.0 adapter stopped working, missing firmware

Tags: 11.04, wireless

When I first installed  11.04 on my gateway ml6720 my gigaware worked fine my son pull out the usb and now I get firmware missing when I try to get online.

My internal wireless works fine but I now can't go far from the house. Is there a way around this or do I have to reinstall the os?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information? It would help us debug the problem.